# Jest click event not firing a ref

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, ts-jest, babel-jest

I created an iframe component with ref and I wanted to create a unit test for that component, then I created a mock iframe so that the component could be run in the unit test, unfortunately the unit test failed, what's wrong with the following code, I'm a beginner at Jest.
So how do you make the unit test successful?

***component***

```
import { forwardRef, useRef, useImperativeHandle } from 'react';
const Iframe = forwardRef(function Iframe(props, ref) {
  const iframeRef = useRef(null);
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => {
    return {
      postMessage() {
        iframeRef.current.contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify({data: 'hello !'}), '*')
      },
    };
  }, []);
  return <iframe {...props} ref={iframeRef} />;
});

export default Iframe;
```

***mock***

```
// __mock__/iframe.js
import { useRef } from 'react';
import Iframe from './Iframe';
export default function App() {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  function handleClick() {
    ref.current.postMessage({data: 'hello !'});
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <Iframe src={'https://www.google.com/'} ref={ref} />
      <button onClick={handleClick}>
        Send Message
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

***jest***

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { render, fireEvent, screen } from '@testing-library/react'
import Iframe from '../__mock__/iframe'
describe('iframe', () => {
  it('call postMessage', () => {
    render(<Iframe />)
    const handleClick = jest.fn()
    const button = screen.getByText(/Send Message/i)
    fireEvent.click(button)
    expect(handleClick).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
})
```

***test failed***
[image]

Comment: 1) Your `handleClick` mock is not attached to anything, it just happens to be called the same as a method in your mock. You have to tell Jest that the empty function you create with `jest.fn()` should replace the real OnClick. 2) You are importing a mock module instead of a real one, so your test does not test your actual code 3) (just a comment on best practices) Your test says `it('calls postMessage')`, but in fact tests only that there is a click handler